# WooCommerce Log Out button not showing (WordPress Plugin)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have installed WooCommerce and everything was going smoothly until I came to registering, logging in and logging out users. I've been googling this all morning and as far as I can see the registration process takes place when the user goes through the check out (if theres any way of having a dedicated registration option I would appreciate it if someone could explain how to go about this) however my main problem is that there is currently no option for the user to log out.

I have checked the option in the settings to "Append a logout link to menus containing 'My Account' " but nothing is showing up under that menu. I am logged in as all of my details are appearing under the My Account page so thats not the problem. I'm working from my localhost but I can't imagine that would be the cause of the problem, and I have also set up a second site to make sure it wasn't a problem with how I installed it and it also wouldn't work. Is there any reason why the option is not showing up and is there any way I can force it to?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: WooCommerce allows you to have a registration form on the same page of the login form, as long as you have checked the `Allow registration on the "My Account" page` option on the WooCommerce Settings page. As long as Log-out link - you are using a WordPress Menu, rendered by `wp_nav_menu()`? If it's a fallback menu(in other words list of all pages, when the specified menu in the `wp_nav_menu()` function is not found) it seems that it's not going to be added.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. You might have to be a little patient with me as I'm new to wordpress! I have enabled the option to allow registration on the My Account page but I haven't been able to see if this was successful or not as I still cant find a method of logging out of my account? I assumed that by enabling the Logout link under the My Account tab in the settings page would provide an additional link but when I check it nothing is showing up?

Comment: For the log-out thing, you have plenty of options(for testing I mean) - use a different browser(or use the "Incognito Mode" of Google Chrome), log-out from the Dashboard(you have a log-out link, under `Howdy {user}` at the top-right of the screen). The user registration form should work in theory, as well as the Log-out link in the menu. Can you tell me which theme you are using? If it's a free one I can test it and tell you where the problem is :)

Comment: I've tested the site using the incognito mode and the registration/login form is working perfectly, however still no logout link under the 'My Account' tab. The theme I'm using is called Mystile however even when I created a second site and applied no theme to it there was still no logout link.

Comment: I'll look into that later today, when I get back home from work :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem and would love to hear any solution!

Comment: I am also still having this problem if anyone can help with this!

Answer (score 2):

Under the "Appearance" tab on the administration area of WordPress, click "Menus" and create your menu. That will activate the logout link.